# argument of type "WCHAR" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char"

Tags: c++

So I was checking csgo scripting with C++ and everything was going smoothly but when I finished the Bhop code I found out that "string1" is "const char" and "string2" is `wchar`. I tried fixing, i searched redit, youtube literally everything but i couldn't fix it.

```
#include "memory.h"
#include <TlHelp32.h>

Memory :: Memory(const char* processName)
{
    
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    

    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    while (Process32Next(snapShot, &entry))
    {
        
        
        
        if (!strcmp(processName, entry.szExeFile))
        {
            this->id = entry.th32ProcessID;
            this->process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, this->id);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (snapShot)
        CloseHandle(this->process);
}


Memory :: ~Memory()
{
    if (this->process)
        CloseHandle(this->process);
}

DWORD Memory :: GetProcessId()
{
    return this->id;
}

HANDLE Memory :: GetProcessHandle()
{
    return this->process;
}

uintptr_t Memory :: GetModuleAdress(const char* moduleName)
{
    MODULEENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, this->id);

    uintptr_t result = 0;

    while (Module32Next(snapShot, &entry))
    {
        if (!strcmp(moduleName, entry.szModule))
        {
            result = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(entry.modBaseAddr);
            break;

        }
    }

    if (snapShot)
        CloseHandle(snapShot);

    return result;
}
```

The  error comes up on `if (!strcmp(processName, entry.szExeFile))` where `processName` is "const char" and `entry.szExeFile` is "wchar". Please tell how to fix my problem
because i got no clue.

Comment: You have 2 strings in 2 different encodings. You can't compare them that way. Either maintain them both in the same encoding or produce a converted version of one of them anytime you want to compare them.

Comment: Have you read the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/windows-data-types-for-strings) on this issue? It's important stuff to be familiar with if you are going to code using the Windows API.

Comment: There are SO MANY questions on StackOverflow regarding this exact kind of error, it would really help if you would search existing questions BEFORE asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `TCHAR`-based Win32 API macros, and you are compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined, so the macros are resolving to the `wchar_t` version of the APIs. But you are using `char` data in the rest of your code, so you need to use the ANSI (`char`) version of the APIs explicitly instead.

Also, there are other bugs in your code. Namely, ignoring the 1st entry in the process and modules lists. And your constructor is closing the wrong `HANDLE`.

Try this:

```
Memory :: Memory(const char* processName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32A entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);

    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (Process32FirstA(snapShot, &entry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (strcmp(processName, entry.szExeFile) == 0)
            {
                this->id = entry.th32ProcessID;
                this->process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, this->id);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (Process32NextA(snapShot, &entry));
    }
    
    if (snapShot)
        CloseHandle(snapShot);
}

uintptr_t Memory :: GetModuleAdress(const char* moduleName)
{
    MODULEENTRY32A entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);

    const auto snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, this->id);

    uintptr_t result = 0;

    if (Module32FirstA(snapShot, &entry))
    {
        do
        {
            if (strcmp(moduleName, entry.szModule) == 0)
            {
                result = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(entry.modBaseAddr);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (Module32NextA(snapShot, &entry));
    }

    if (snapShot)
        CloseHandle(snapShot);

    return result;
}
```